# Can I reuse variables in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis

In a starting point , I use a variable " id" for a particular task . Then in a final package point , I require use that same variable to a completely different task . You can reuse ? or should I create new variables?

Comment: As long as the scope is the same, yes, you can continue to reference the same variable.

Comment: What is the variable type?   I have found that object-type variables sometimes can't be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reuse variables if they are scoped to the package as a whole.

A typical example is a "Rowcount" variable that populated several times during the course of the package, and the number contained used for logging or validation as the package runs.